# Can't fix java cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

I'm working on a project and I can't figure out how to fix this error. I am calling for an integer from a different method with

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int foo = 0;
    foo = method(foo);
}
public static int method(){
    int foo = (equation)
    return foo;
}
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        foo = method(foo);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable foo
  location: class MainClass
```

I declared foo as an int in a separate method and I returned foo at the end of it. But when trying to call for it in the main method I got that error.

Comment: supplying code would be a start

Comment: ... ok how about all the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't say

```
int foo = method(foo);
```

because there is no value assigned to `foo` which might be passed to `method`. You could do something like,

```
int foo = 0; // <-- Initialize foo to 0
foo = method(foo); // <-- passes foo
```

When you declare your method, first `(equation)` isn't valid code. Second, you aren't declaring that it takes an `int` argument. Change `method` like

```
public static int method(int foo){
  int x = foo * foo; // <-- equation?
  return x;
}
```

Or,

```
int foo = method(); // if method takes no arguments.
```

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work, I've updated my code in the question, perhaps it'll add more insight.

Comment: There we go it doesn't take an argument, and yes equation was just a place holder for other stuff I had coded there thanks for the help